# MahApps.Metro Progress Ring speed change

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I use the progress ring in XAML like in the guide:

```
<Controls:ProgressRing IsActive="True" />
```

Is there any way to control the speed of a progress ring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProgressRing` does not have properties to control the speed. However, you can implement your own style. Take [the default style](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Themes/ProgressRing.xaml) as a starting point, you will see the timing there.